# Python Pandas Groupby -- by = list giving me an error?

Tags: python, pandas, list

Programming Newbie, forgive me if this is really simple

I know we should be able to use a list to groupby in pandas, and they have to be of equal length, but somehow I'm not able to make it work?

Using the Titanic dataset from seaborn
Function to define age groups

```
def age_groups(x):
    array = []
    for i in x['age']:
        if(math.isnan(i)):
            array.append(9)
        if(i < 20):
            array.append(1)
        if(i < 40):
            array.append(2)
        if(i < 60):
            array.append(3)
        else:
            array.append(4)
    return array

groups = age_groups(titanic)
titanic.groupby(groups).mean()
```

I get the following error

> File "pandas\hashtable.pyx", line 683, in
>   pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas\hashtable.c:12322)
>
> KeyError: 2

Thank in advance

Comment: When you use `dataframe.groupby()`, the main parameter of  `groupby` should be one of the dataframe's labels or a list of labels, here is the [doc] (https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an easier way to get the age groups and that is to use [`numpy.digitize`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.digitize.html), which returns an integer depending on which bin a value belongs to, with `0` and `len(bins)` (here `5`) being under- and overflow, respectively. `NaN`'s seem to go into the overflow (since they do not compare smaller than any number).

```
groups = np.digitize(titanic.age, [0, 20, 40, 60, titanic.age.max() + 1])
titanic.groupby(groups).age.mean()
# 1    11.979695
# 2    28.580103
# 3    47.354015
# 4    65.096154
# 5          NaN
# Name: age, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Thanks, that's perfect

Answer (score 1):

You need to ensure that the variable you pass to the groupby function is contained in the dataframe:

```
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np

titanic = sns.load_dataset('titanic')

titanic['groups'] = titanic['age']
titanic.loc[np.isnan(titanic.age), 'groups'] = 9
titanic.loc[titanic.age >= 60, 'groups'] = 4
titanic.loc[titanic.age < 60, 'groups'] = 3
titanic.loc[titanic.age < 40, 'groups'] = 2
titanic.loc[titanic.age < 20, 'groups'] = 1
titanic.groupby('groups').mean()


        survived    pclass        age  ...       fare  adult_male     alone
groups                                 ...                                 
1.0     0.481707  2.530488  11.979695  ...  31.794741    0.298780  0.329268
2.0     0.387597  2.304910  28.580103  ...  32.931200    0.658915  0.653747
3.0     0.394161  1.824818  47.354015  ...  41.481784    0.635036  0.569343
4.0     0.269231  1.538462  65.096154  ...  43.467950    0.846154  0.730769
9.0     0.293785  2.598870        NaN  ...  22.158567    0.700565  0.751412

[5 rows x 8 columns]
```

Comment: No problem! Happy to help.